# Inserting css properties to a database

Tags: php, css

How would I add the properties of css, in this case the left and top of an element into php so I can reuse them again as the css properties?

for example:
use

```
<input id = "enter" name="enter" style = "top: 20;float: left;width: 300px;">
```

to enter the left and top to the database, this isn't how you do it but it would be something life

```
    $input = (empty($_POST['enter'])) ? : $_POST['enter'] ;
```

but with something like

```
    $input = (empty($_POST['enter'].style.top)) ? : $_POST['enter'] ;
```

so I could reuse them later on and say something like

```
    <input id = "enter" name="enter" style = "$input,float: left;width: 300px;">
```

What is the closest thing to this, or how could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing about the style attribute will be sent to the server by default.

If you want to pass that information then you will have to do so explicitly.

For example, you could use JavaScript to read the data and generate (with `createElement`, `appendChild`, etc.) hidden input element in the form.